# Simply-Connected Condition in Cauchy's Thm.

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the following statement of Cauchy's theorem

**Cauchy**: If $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ is open and simply connected, and $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$, then for $\gamma$ smooth, closed curve, $\int_{\gamma} f d\gamma = 0$.

In the following proof, let us use Green's theorem, stated as follows:

**Green**: For $\Omega$ open,  bounded with piecewise smooth boundary $\partial \Omega$, and $f,g \in \mathcal{C}^1(\overline{\Omega})$ (that is, they are continuous on $\Omega$, and have continuous partial derivatives on $\Omega$, which continuously extend to $\overline{\Omega}$), we have: $\int_{\partial\Omega} fdx + g dy = \int \int_{\Omega} (g_x - f_y) dx dy$

**Proof:** (i) Supposing $\gamma$ is a simple curve in $\Omega$, so it encloses some region $\Gamma \subset \Omega$, note: $\int_{\gamma} f d \gamma = \int f(dx + idy) = \int \int_{\Gamma} if_x - f_y dx dy = 0 $.

(ii) Thereafter, for general $\gamma$ smooth and closed, note that $\gamma = \cup_j \gamma_j$, where $\gamma_j$ are simple. But then, $\int_{\gamma} f d\gamma = \sum_j \int_{\gamma_j} f d\gamma_j = \sum_j 0 = 0$.

**Question:** Where in the above proof do we require that $\Omega$ is simply connected? I certainly think it is needed in $(i)$ (since, for example, $(i)$ should not work for the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}/\{0\}$), but then this should mean that Green's theorem doesn't work on that domain. However, I'm unable to reason why: the only counterexample I know to Cauchy's theorem is $\frac{1}{z}$, and this seems to fail not because of topological reasons, but because its partials don't continuously extend at the origin.

---

This statement of Green's theorem is from Taylor's Introduction to Complex Analysis, Theorem 2.1.1. This statement of Cauchy is from Exercise 10 in the same section.

Comment: "So it encloses..."

Comment: @MoisheKohan Is it even trivial to say that a general $C^1$ curve $\gamma$ is necessarily the boundary of a $C^1$-parametrisable domain $\Gamma$, if $\Omega$ is simply connected?

Comment: @FShrike: If you are generous enough with your definition of a parametrizable domain (which is then not a domain but a smooth map of a disk), then yes, provided you are using topological definition of simple connectivity. (I saw some really weird definitions that complex analysts came up with.)

Comment: @MoisheKohan Roughly how does that go? Take a $C^1$ injection $\gamma:S^1\to\Omega$, it is nullhomotopic, it therefore extends to a map $D^2\to\Omega$... but that map in general need not be injective, right? Or $C^1$. How do we fix that?

Comment: @FShrike: I did not say injective. Smooth one gets by a suitable approximation argument, I think it was discussed many times on MSE. As for injectivity, this was discussed too. But, most likely, the textbook uses a different definition of simple connectivity, one where every smooth Jordan curve bounds a disk. This is actually quite common in CA textbooks.

Comment: So you want to reason about a non-simply connected $\Omega$.  So, $\Omega$ is the annulus $\{z \in  \Bbb{C} \mid 1< |z| < 3\}$ and $\gamma$ is $2\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$ for $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, the circle running down the middle of the annulus.  What does $\gamma$ enclose?